# Cannot apt-get - Package install issue

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I was halfway through updating my machine when it crashed and I had to reboot.

It was updating new packages while it crashed.

When I try to use `apt-get` it always fails because of a `mysql` package.

```
mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
```

Typging `sudo apt-get -f install` returns the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1); however:
  Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.     
                                                                                                     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by installing directly the package from the download cache:

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the package completely using

```
apt-get remove --purge package
```

then re-install it with

```
apt-get install
```

you might need to using `su` to do that.